# WebSocketException (0x80004005) only when running in the docker container (WebSocket closed without the close handshake)

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, websocket

I have a simple project created from the template Worker Service with SDK 8.0. It has one worker (BackgroundService) that is reading a stream using ClientWebSocket.

I successfully received the messages when running as a standalone application or the application within the docker container.

```
public class Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://url.com/stream"), stoppingToken);

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var buffer = WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer(1024, 1024);
            var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, stoppingToken);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Socket closed");
                break;
            }

            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray(), 0, result.Count);
            logger.LogInformation("Message received: {Message}", json);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I'm running the application in the docker container, it fails always after one minute (~60 seconds). It does not happen when it is run as a standalone application.

**System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake**.

```
2023-12-31 14:48:48       System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowEOFUnexpected()
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32 minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
2023-12-31 14:48:48       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at GotifyToPushover.Worker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in C:\Test\GotifyToPushover\Worker.cs:line 25
2023-12-31 14:48:48          at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.TryExecuteBackgroundServiceAsync(BackgroundService backgroundService)
```

I experience the same when using a local Docker environment and when using the Alpine server with Docker.
I've tried adding some logging, and a ping method to keep the socket alive, but without any luck. Not sure what is the reason, but I do not suspect the server since it only happens inside Docker container. Any ideas?

Comment: `using var ws =.....` you need to dispose it properly.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the suggestion, but the issue persists after applying.

Comment: Could be a firewall or NAT router intervening. Maybe set the `ws.Options.KeepAliveInterval` to less than 1 minute. What does the code for the server look like?

Comment: Not sure how NAT/firewall could affect this and how to verify it - the same behavior occurs when the container is running locally and on the Alpine host, but not for the application runs as a standalone. The server is a self-hosted gotify instance (https://github.com/gotify/server).

I was trying with ```ws.Options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)```, but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to host Gotify server in a Docker container on Alpine which is running as LXC container. That is a shared budget server, not fully under my control and there are some restrictions regarding ports.

**There seem to be some restrictions in the server regarding open WebSocket connections, which are forcibly closed after one minute. I could not confirm it with the server admin, but after moving Gotify server to another place, the client is running without interruptions.**

@Charlieface, thank you for your input and time.